# How to get all record from a table where particular column exists on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables like CandidateExam and PaperDetails. Each and every student is associated with paper(i.g. if 2 candidate are there and 2 paper are  there in PaperDetails then 4 entries will be exist in CandidateExam) . I want to check all candidate which are not associate with particular paper.
Note : please try to avaid NOT IN

Please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't give details but it will be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM CandidateExam CE
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM PaperDetails PD WHERE CE.CandidateID = PD.CandidateID)
```

Comment: NOT EXISTS and NOT IN are not optimized way :(

Comment: Detailed way is like both table are having paperID as a common field

Comment: Generally speaking, searching for not existence is not great for performance.

Comment: Actually `NOT EXISTS` is usually the **most** efficient way. See Aaron Bertrand's blog: **[Should I use NOT IN, OUTER APPLY, LEFT OUTER JOIN, EXCEPT, or NOT EXISTS?](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)**